# Rails: How to have a nested form save to different nested models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, nested-forms

**Context:**

I have a `Company` model that has many `projects`. Each `project` has many `tasks`. The `company` has many `employees`.

`Employee` belongs to `Company` and has many `tasks`. It is one employee per task and an employee will have only one `task` per `project`.

**Schema:**

[image]

**Problem:**

I'm building a form to create a project where the user can add multiple `tasks`. Each task has an amount of `hours` specified and the `employee` performing the `task`. Upon submission the form should create a single `project` record, one or more `task` records with `hours` and `employee_id` attributes and (!) check if the `employee` name already exists in the database or create a new one.

I'm struggling with how to have the form save the `employee_id` rather than the `employee_name`.

**Code:**

My form is as follows:

```
<%= simple_nested_form_for @project do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :project_details %>
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :tasks do |task| %>
        <%= task.input :employee_name, input_html: { data: { autocomplete_source: @queried_employee_names.to_json } } %>
        <%= task.input :hours %>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.link_to_add "Add +", :tasks %>
    <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

My controller:

```
class TransactionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @project = current_company.projects.build
  end

  def create
    @project = current_company.projects.new(project_params)
    if @project.save
        employee_save
        redirect_to success_url
    else
        @project = current_company.projects.build
        render :new
    end
  end


    # save the employees not yet in the database
    def employee_save
      @project.tasks.each do |task|
            if current_company.employees.where(name: task.employee_name).empty?
              current_company.employees.new(name: task.employee_name).save 
            end
        end
    end

  def project_params
    params.require(:project).permit(:project_details, tasks_attributes: [:id, :employee_name, :hours, :_destroy])
  end
end
```

**Question:**

Unfortunately, this would save to the `tasks` table the `employee_name` rather than `employee_id` (plus writing a new `employee_name` to the `employees table`). Of course, the `tasks` table should only contain the `employee_ids` and the `employee` table the `names`.

Any suggestions on how to approach this?

Comment: Hi if my answer was useful, please consider select it as accepted answer, that's how the community works...

Comment: Hi SsouLlesS, thanks for the answer and your time. Quite frankly the answer (comment) by j-dexx was most useful here. You mentioned the use of a hidden field, which in the end I did not use. Perhaps if you would summarise the comments mentioned below I will accept. Currently it is not 'the' solution. Cheers, M

Comment: Yes I know it was not the full answer, but it may be useful for others looking for this same topic, not because it was not useful only for you means it is not an useful answer. Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add a hidden field in the form like:

```
<%= simple_nested_form_for @project do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :project_details %>
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :tasks do |task| %>
        <%= task.input :employee_name, input_html: { data: { autocomplete_source: @queried_employee_names.to_json } } %>
        <%= task.hidden_field :employee_id, '' %>
        <%= task.input :hours %>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.link_to_add "Add +", :tasks %>
    <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

This field must be filled through Ajax. I see you have an autocomplete source in your `:employee_name` input field, well you can add an event there when you select the employee, and get the id through Ajax and fill the hidden field with the id of the selected employee, that way you can easily save that data in your `create` action.

Comment: thanks. That indeed sounds like a solution. Do you also have a suggestion how to deal with this on the controller side?

Comment: It's an old episode but [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/57-create-model-through-text-field) would work for you

Comment: Good suggestion to watch the Railscast. I actually found a more recent one [#102](http://railscasts.com/episodes/102-auto-complete-association) that even better describes this issue. There is one remaining issue however, how to link the new `employee` record to `company` this way. I've described this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35494349/rails-how-to-make-available-parent-attribute-in-setter-method). Thanks again!