# Rails: How to make available parent attribute in setter method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes, getter-setter, virtual-attribute

**Context:**

I have a `company` model with many `projects`, having many `tasks`. The `company` also has many `employees`, which in turn have many `tasks`.

**Schema:**

[image]

**Problem:**

I'm building a form to create a project where the user can add multiple `tasks`. Upon submission the form should create a single `project` record, one or more `task` records with `hours` and `employee_id` attributes and (!) check if the `employee` name already exists in the database or create a new one.

I've approached this by adding jquery `autocomplete` to the form and defining a virtual attribute with a `getter` and `setter` method in my Task model. Similar to [Railscast #102](http://railscasts.com/episodes/102-auto-complete-association).

This succesfully sets the `employee_id` in `tasks` and creates a new `employee` record with employee `name` and `task_id`.

The problem is currently that the model does not save a `company_id`.

**My code:**

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :project
    belongs_to :employee

    def employee_name
      employee.try(:name)
    end

    def employee_name=(name)
      self.employee = Employee.find_or_create_by(name: name) if name.present?
    end
end
```

**Question:**

How can I make the `company_id` attribute of the parent model available the setter method of my `Task` model? Like so:

```
def shareholder_name=(name)
    self.shareholder = Shareholder.find_or_create_by(name: name, company_id: company_id) if name.present?
end
```

At the moment this yields the error:

`undefined local variable or method "company_id" for #<Task:0x98438b8>`

**EDIT:**

Or, if I try `project.company_id` this tells me `project` is a NilClass:

`undefined method company_id for nil:NilClass`

**UPDATE:**

Still unsolved. Any ideas why `project` is `nil` here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :employee

  def shareholder_name=(name)
    self.shareholder = Shareholder.find_or_create_by(name: name, company_id: project.company_id) if name.present?
  end
end
```

also, so typical pattern with rails, for instance where you have `belongs_to :project`, that would add an instance method called `project` to `Task`, that instance method could then be used to get project associated with task and subsequently the associated `company_id` in case that may be of interest

Comment: Hi @Drew, thanks for your answer. I indeed got that far myself. I think the question of my post should have been how to get the `company_id` attribute accessible in the `Task` model. Any suggestions?

Comment: response revised with what if I had to guess could facilitate getting `company_id` in `Task` in case that may be of interest

Comment: Hmm, if I add to the setter method (`company_id: foo`) and `def foo` as `project.company_id`, I get the exception `no block given (yield)`.

Comment: you wouldn't have your revised code off-hand by any chance would you?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'off-hand'?

Comment: oh sorry, in other words available without preperation, or at the ready

Comment: also, response revised! in case that may be of interest

Comment: Thanks @Drew. Unfortunately, this also gives me a LocalJumpError `no block given (yield)`. Would there be a way to explicitly pass this attribute from the `Project` model to my  `Task` model?

Comment: Hi @Drew, regarding your "off-hand" question and in case you still feel helpful, see the unredacted version here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35536824/rails-why-is-my-parent-model-nil-in-child-model :-)

Comment: matthias, guessing there is no project associated with the task. had you been creating a new record? or thoughts?